# Increasing energy density for flow batteries with water based electrolyte?

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions, energy

Given a flow battery with a water based electrolyte, would it be possible to increase the energy density of battery by precipitating the redox active species from the anolyte and catholyte solutions? I am assuming the main limiting factor in energy density of flow batteries is limits on how much of the redox active species can be dissolved in water.

To give an example, say both the catholyte and anolyte tanks have two chambers: the active chamber and the precipitation chamber. The active chamber is where the normal solution would exist. Above a certain concentration, the solution would be pumped to the precipitation chamber where the water and active species would be separated and the pure water would be pumped back to the active chamber decreasing its active species concentration. A naive way to separate the water and active species might be to evaporate the water and condense it back in the active chamber. Chemistry is not my strong suit, so I could be totally off base.

Comment: Please give us a real example of a stuff which could be precipitated from anolytic and catholytic chambers. Also what is an "active chamber" separated from a " precipitation chamber" ?

Comment: What would be precipitated is part of my question. If the water is evaporated, I would assume that due to the limits on solubility of the active species that something would precipitate out (maybe I'm wrong). The active chamber is the standard chamber for the anolyte/catholyte you see in a flow battery.